# How can I show this polynomial is irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials

I would like to show the polynomial $x^p - (1 + p)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}_p[x]$. My idea was that if there was a root $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, then taking absolute values shows that it would be in $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. I then wanted to conclude there could be no solution to $x^p \equiv 1 + p \bmod p^2$, but I am not sure how to show this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is integrally closed in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ any root of $f(x) := x^p-(1+p)$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is necessarily already in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. However, this doesn't help much since having no roots is not enough to be irreducible. Here is one way to do it:

Since (the extension of) $x \mapsto x+1$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}_p[x]$ the polynomial $f(x)$ is irreducible if and only if $f(x+1)$ is. Now $f(x+1)=(x+1)^p -(1+p) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^p {{p}\choose{i}}x^i\right) + 1- 1 -p = \left(\sum_{i=1}^p {{p}\choose{i}}x^i\right) - p$. This is a monic polynomial all of whose coefficients (except for the leading one) are divisible by $p$ (if you do not know this, look at the prime factorization of the enumerator and denominator in ${p \choose i}$) and the constant term is divisible by $p$ exactly once. Thus by Eisenstein's criterion $f(x+1)$ and consequently also $f(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: Ah of course, I can't believe I didn't see this. Thanks!